# How do I handle too long index names in a Ruby on Rails ActiveRecord migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, indexing, migration

I am trying to add a unique index that gets created from the foreign keys of four associated tables:

```
add_index :studies,
  ["user_id", "university_id", "subject_name_id", "subject_type_id"],
  :unique => true
```

The database’s limitation for the index name causes the migration to fail. Here’s the error message:

> Index name 'index_studies_on_user_id_and_university_id_and_subject_name_id_and_subject_type_id' on table 'studies' is too long; the limit is 64 characters

How can I handle this? Can I specify a different index name?

Answer (score 740, accepted):

Provide the `:name` option to [`add_index`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_index), e.g.:

```
add_index :studies,
  ["user_id", "university_id", "subject_name_id", "subject_type_id"], 
  unique: true,
  name: 'my_index'
```

If using the `:index` option on [`references`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/Table.html#method-i-references) in a `create_table` block, it takes the same options hash as `add_index` as its value:

```
t.references :long_name, index: { name: :my_index }
```

Comment: According to APIdock the name has to be a string, not a symbol

Comment: The down syntax for this is `remove_index :studies, :name => 'my_index'` for anyone who needs it

Comment: On Rails `4.2.6` works with `index: { name: :my_index }`. Only `name` did not work.

Comment: I don't think ApiDock is accurate, if you look at the code [schema_statements.rb] the :name field has to_s run on it [as it should really]

Answer (score 214):

You can change the index name in column definitions within a `create_table` block (such as you get from the migration generator).

```
create_table :studies do |t|
  t.references :user, index: {:name => "index_my_shorter_name"}
end
```

Comment: Note that this doesn't create the multi-column index from the original question; it's just demonstrating how to shorten a long index name from a `create_table`

Comment: This helped me when I was trying to create a polymorphic reference on a name spaced table with an index `t.references :searchable, polymorphic:true, index: {:name => "index_searches_on_searchable"}` in this case the index was in fact a multi-column(searchable_id and searchable_type) and the addition of the namespace in the generated name became very long.

Comment: Should also have `foreign_key: true` and by the way, this is a great solution since it's the easiest to use when you have a migration file created with the rails generator `model:references` format

Answer (score 48):

In PostgreSQL, [the *default* limit is 63 characters](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS). Because index names must be unique it's nice to have a little convention. I use (I tweaked the example to explain more complex constructions):

```
def change
  add_index :studies, [:professor_id, :user_id], name: :idx_study_professor_user
end
```

The normal index would have been:

```
:index_studies_on_professor_id_and_user_id
```

The logic would be:

- `index` becomes `idx`
- Singular table name
- No joining words
- No `_id`
- Alphabetical order

Which usually does the job.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Would be nice if you could link the Postgres documentation for the limitation fact.

Comment: Do we need the table name in the index name since the index belongs to that table anyway? Just curious if that's beneficial somewhere I haven't seen.

Comment: You can name the index what you want, but I think the table name in the index name helps to keep the index name unique (which is mandatory), well scoped and improves some error message readability.

Answer (score 25):

You can also do

```
t.index([:branch_id, :party_id], unique: true, name: 'by_branch_party')
```

as in the [Ruby on Rails API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/Table.html#method-i-index).

Answer (score 8):

Similar to the previous answer: Just use the 'name' key with your regular add_index line:

```
def change
  add_index :studies, :user_id, name: 'my_index'
end
```

Answer (score 8):

I'm afraid none of these solutions worked for me. Perhaps because I was using `belongs_to` in my create_table migration for a polymorphic association.

I'll add my code below and a link to the solution that helped me in case anyone else stumbles upon when searching for 'Index name is too long' in connection with polymorphic associations.

The following code did NOT work for me:

```
def change
  create_table :item_references do |t|
    t.text :item_unique_id
    t.belongs_to :referenceable, polymorphic: true
    t.timestamps
  end
  add_index :item_references, [:referenceable_id, :referenceable_type], name: 'idx_item_refs'
end
```

This code DID work for me:

```
def change
  create_table :item_references do |t|
    t.text :item_unique_id
    t.belongs_to :referenceable, polymorphic: true, index: { name: 'idx_item_refs' }

    t.timestamps
  end
end
```

This is the SO Q&A that helped me out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30366460/3258059

Answer (score 5):

I have a project that uses generators a lot and needed this to be automatic, so I copied the `index_name` function from the rails source to override it. I added this in `config/initializers/generated_index_name.rb`:

```rb
# make indexes shorter for postgres
require "active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements"
module ActiveRecord
  module ConnectionAdapters # :nodoc:
    module SchemaStatements
      def index_name(table_name, options) #:nodoc:
        if Hash === options
          if options[:column]
            "ix_#{table_name}_on_#{Array(options[:column]) * '__'}".slice(0,63)
          elsif options[:name]
            options[:name]
          else
            raise ArgumentError, "You must specify the index name"
          end
        else
          index_name(table_name, index_name_options(options))
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

It creates indexes like `ix_assignments_on_case_id__project_id` and just truncates it to 63 characters if it's still too long. That's still going to be non-unique if the table name is very long, but you can add complications like shortening the table name separately from the column names or actually checking for uniqueness.

Note, this is from a Rails 5.2 project; if you decide to do this, copy the source from your version.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue, but with the `timestamps` function. It was autogenerating an index on updated_at that exceeded the 63 character limit:

```
def change
  create_table :toooooooooo_loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong do |t|
    t.timestamps
  end
end
```

> Index name 'index_toooooooooo_loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong_on_updated_at' on table 'toooooooooo_loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong' is too long; the limit is 63 characters

I tried to use `timestamps` to specify the index name:

```
def change
  create_table :toooooooooo_loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong do |t|
    t.timestamps index: { name: 'too_loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong_updated_at' }
  end
end
```

However, this tries to apply the index name to both the `updated_at` and `created_at` fields:

> Index name 'too_long_updated_at' on table 'toooooooooo_loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong' already exists

Finally I gave up on `timestamps` and just created the timestamps the long way:

```
def change
  create_table :toooooooooo_loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong do |t|
    t.datetime :updated_at, index: { name: 'too_long_on_updated_at' }
    t.datetime :created_at, index: { name: 'too_long_on_created_at' }
  end
end
```

This works but I'd love to hear if it's possible with the `timestamps` method!

Answer (score 1):

create_table :you_table_name do |t|
    t.references :studant, index: { name: 'name_for_studant_index' }
    t.references :teacher, index: { name: 'name_for_teacher_index' }
end