# Specify custom index name when using add_reference

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-migrations

I have the following migration

```
class LinkDoctorsAndSpecializations < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    add_reference :doctors, :doctor_specialization, polymorphic: true, index: true
  end

  def down
    remove_reference :doctors, :doctor_specialization, polymorphic: true
  end
end
```

when i run `rake db:migrate` i am getting the error

`Index name 'index_doctors_on_doctor_specialization_type_and_doctor_specialization_id' on table 'doctors' is too long; the limit is 63 characters`

so how can i specify the index name when using add_reference like the way we specify in `add_index :table, :column, :name => 'index name'`

Comment: You should do `add_index :table, :column, :name => 'index name'`

Answer (score 65, accepted):

As I [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30366315/how-to-specify-index-name-when-using-add-reference-in-rails-migrations/30366460#comment48823717_30366315), do :

```
add_index :table, :column, name: 'index name'
```

Here is [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/TableDefinition.html#method-i-column).
Or, you can try this :

```
class LinkDoctorsAndSpecializations < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_reference :doctors, :doctor_specialization, polymorphic: true, index: { name: 'index name' }
  end
end
```

Comment: I would suggest to emphasise the second part of your answer (passing a hash with the name to index: in `add_reference` - That seems to be the intended way to do it, using `add_index`an alternative.

Answer (score 5):

This would actually work:

```
add_index :table, :column, name: 'index name'
```

[Take a look](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/add_index) for more examples.

Answer (score 4):

I would not suggest leaving out "add_reference", but you could leave out the "index" option hash key and then use "add_index":

```
add_reference :table, :column
add_index :table, :column, :name => 'index_table_column'
```

Or, the more appropriate way would be like this:

```
add_reference :doctors, :doctor_specialization, polymorphic: true, index: { name: 'index_doctors_doctor_specialization' }
```

Comment: This is a duplicate [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30366460/2767755).

Answer (score 0):

I've heard the best way to fix this is to just leave it out of the add reference line and specify it manually below much like in the last line of your question

```
add_index :table, :column, :name => 'index name'
```