# Rails LHM migration - specify name of index

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, soundcloud, database-migration

Using LHM ([Large Hadron Migrator](https://github.com/soundcloud/lhm)) there is syntax documentation to add indexes:

```
require 'lhm'
class SomeMigration < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    Lhm.change_table :foos do |m|
      m.add_unique_index  [:bar_id, :baz] # add_index if you don't want uniqueness
    end
  end
  def self.down
    Lhm.change_table :foos do |m|
      m.remove_index  [:bar_id, :baz]
    end
  end
end
```

How can a specific name for the index be specified in LHM? For adding and removing

I am concerned I will hit the [index name length limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5443740/how-to-handle-too-long-index-names-in-a-rails-migration-with-mysql) as I am using many columns

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
m.add_unique_index([:long_column, :super_long_column], 'shortened_index_name')
```

[Link to LHM docs for #add_unique_index](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/lhm/Lhm%2FMigrator%3Aadd_unique_index)

Comment: Aha! I tried `name: 'blah'` but it was expecting `index_name: 'blah'`