# Index name "index_name" is too long; the limit is 63 characters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, indexing, migration

when I'm running rails migration command. I'm getting index name is too long.
My migration file

```
class AddMissingIndices < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    # We'll explicitly specify its name, as the auto-generated name is too long and exceeds 63
    # characters limitation.
    add_index :mailboxer_conversation_opt_outs, [:unsubscriber_id, :unsubscriber_type],
      name: 'index_mailboxer_conversation_opt_outs_on_unsubscriber_id_type'
    add_index :mailboxer_conversation_opt_outs, :conversation_id

    add_index :mailboxer_notifications, :type
    add_index :mailboxer_notifications, [:sender_id, :sender_type]

    # We'll explicitly specify its name, as the auto-generated name is too long and exceeds 63
    # characters limitation.
    add_index :mailboxer_notifications, [:notified_object_id, :notified_object_type],
      name: 'index_mailboxer_notifications_on_notified_object_id_and_type'

    add_index :mailboxer_receipts, [:receiver_id, :receiver_type]
  end
end
```

Server logs are

> rails aborted!
>
> StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:
>
> Index name 'index_mailboxer_conversation_opt_outs_on_unsubscriber_type_and_unsubscriber_id' on table 'mailboxer_conversation_opt_outs' is too long; the limit is 63 characters
>   /home/sharat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.3/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:1353:in `validate_index_length!'
>   /home/sharat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.3/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:1166:in`add_index_options'
>   /home/sharat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.3/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/schema_statements.rb:465:in `add_index'
>   /home/sharat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.3/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:315:in`block in create_table'
>   /home/sharat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.3/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:314:in `each'
>   /home/sharat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.3/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:314:in`create_table'
>   /home/sharat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.3/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:871:in `block in method_missing'
>   /home/sharat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.3/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:840:in`block in say_with_time'
>   /home/sharat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.3/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:840:in `say_with_time'
>   /home/sharat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.3/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:860:in`method_missing'
>   /home/sharat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.3/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/migration/compatibility.rb:36:in `create_table'
>   /home/sharat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.3/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/migration/compatibility.rb:75:in`create_table'
>   /home/sharat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.3/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:604:in `method_missing'
>   /home/sharat/rahul/Fleet-Latest/db/migrate/20170425092621_add_conversation_optout.mailboxer_engine.rb:4:in`up'
>   /home/sharat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.3/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:777:in `up'

Comment: This stackoverflow answer might help you. Check it out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5443740/how-do-i-handle-too-long-index-names-in-a-ruby-on-rails-migration-with-mysql

Comment: there's ahard limit for identfier (unless you compile different)

Comment: This stackoverflow answer might help you. Check it out.(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5443740/how-do-i-handle-too-long-index-names-in-a-ruby-on-rails-migration-with-mysql)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try creating the index with a custom (and shorter) name:

`add_index(:accounts, [:branch_id, :party_id], unique: true, name: 'my_custom_and_shorter_name')`

Since you already have the `name` field there, just change the index name :)

Answer (score 2):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html

> The system uses no more than NAMEDATALEN-1 bytes of an identifier;
>   longer names can be written in commands, but they will be truncated.
>   By default, NAMEDATALEN is 64 so the maximum identifier length is 63
>   bytes. If this limit is problematic, it can be raised by changing the
>   NAMEDATALEN constant in src/include/pg_config_manual.h.

so unless you really want it and wish to recompile, 63 is a hard limit for the identifier

Comment: this type of error was not there for rails 5.0.7 when I updated my rails to 5.2 I am getting this error.... what I have to do to get rid of this error