# Rails 5.2 migration failed due to long index name

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I was trying to do migration `rake db:migration` to add new table as well as new indexes.
However, I got this error:

```
Caused by:
ArgumentError: Index name 'index_cite_this_article_referencings_on_referencer_type_and_referencer_id' on table 'cite_this_article_referencings' is too long; the limit is 64 characters
```

Which is understandable, but after I define the name of index, the migration doesn't take my self-defined index name and still give the same error.

Here is my migration:

```
class CreateCiteThisArticleReferencings < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :cite_this_article_referencings do |t|
      t.belongs_to :article
      t.belongs_to :referencer, polymorphic: true

      t.timestamps
      t.index [:article_id], name: "cite_this_article_referencings_a_id", unique: true
      t.index [:referencer_id], name: "cite_this_article_referencings_r_id", unique: true
      t.index [:referencer_id, :referencer_type], name: "cite_this_article_referencings_all_ids", unique: true
    end

  end
end
```

The migration can't catch the `cite_this_article_referencings_all_ids`; instead, it still uses its own created name `index_cite_this_article_referencings_on_referencer_type_and_referencer_id`

Rails 5.2.3; Ruby 2.5.1; MacOS Mojave.
Thanks for any help!

Comment: This has been answered before.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5443740/how-do-i-handle-too-long-index-names-in-a-ruby-on-rails-activerecord-migration

Comment: @JasonBrodie Hi Thanks for the links. The `belong_to` is tricky...

Answer (score 0):

Provide the :name option to [add_index](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_index), e.g.:

```
add_index :cite_this_article_referencings,
  [:referencer_id, :referencer_type], 
  :unique => true,
  :name => 'my_index'
```